# wget bash script with parameters

Tags: bash, wget

I'm running a bash script using

```
wget -O - https://myserver/install/Setup.sh | bash
```

How can I pass a parameter to the above script so it runs? something like

```
wget -O - https://myserver/install/Setup.sh parameter1 | bash
```

Comment: Like that, yes. Provided that which is fetched by wget is of course valid input for bash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard format for the `bash` (or `sh` or similar) command is `bash scriptfilename arg1 arg2 ...`. If you leave off all the first argument (the name or path of the script to run), it reads the script from stdin. Unfortunately, there's no way to leave off the firs argument but pass the others. Fortunately, you can pass `/dev/stdin` as the first argument and get the same effect (at least on most unix systems):

```
wget -O - https://myserver/install/Setup.sh | bash /dev/stdin parameter1
```

If you're on a system that doesn't have /dev/stdin, you might have to look around for an alternative way to specify stdin explicitly (/dev/fd/0 or something like that).

Edit: Léa Gris suggestion of `bash -s arg1 arg2 ...` is probably a better way to do this.

Comment: @GordonDavisson You missed about the `bash -s parameter1` option and the `bash -c command parameter0 parameter1` alternatives that may be more system agnostic. I documented these in my answer below

Comment: @LéaGris I *did* completely miss the `-s` option; nice!

Answer (score 9):

You can also run your script with:

```
wget -qO - 'https://myserver/install/Setup.sh' | bash -s parameter1
```

See: [`man bash` OPTIONS `-s`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#OPTIONS)

> ```
>    -s        If the -s option is present, or if no arguments remain
>              after option processing, then commands are read from the
>              standard input.  This option allows the positional
>              parameters to be set when invoking an interactive shell or
>              when reading input through a pipe.
> ```

or alternatively use the `-c` option.

```
bash -c "$(wget -qO - 'https://myserver/install/Setup.sh')" '' parameter1
```

the `''` defines the parameter `$0` to be empty string. In a normal file based script invocation, the parameter `$0` contains the caller script name.

See: [`man bash` OPTIONS `-c`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#OPTIONS)

> ```
>    -c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from
>              the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are
>              arguments after the command_string, the first argument is
>              assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to
>              the positional parameters.  The assignment to $0 sets the
>              name of the shell, which is used in warning and error
>              messages.
> ```

Comment: Can use bash `--` so that all parameters that follow are passed to the script and not interpreted by bash command e.g. for script parameter `--param2` would be `bash -s -- --param2`